# What type of Math and how to solve (points and distance)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I think it has to do with geometry and algebra.

We have a rectangle with four points.

1. We know each point as $(0,0), (0,10),(10,10)$ and $(10,0)$.
2. In the rectangle we have another point $(x,y)$.
3. The distance from this point to the other points is known: $a,b,c,d$

How do we figure out $x,y$ of the point?

Comment: Do you know which corner is $a$ units from $(x,y)$?  If not, there will be at least eight solutions (unless $(x,y)$ is at a symmetric location)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the following image and try so set up the equations. (Pythagoras)
[image]

Comment: We have a distance $a$, because of pythogoras we have $x^2+y^2=a^2$. There are more trianges like this in the square. So we can set up equations solve $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Comment: Thank you, I can work off of this

Comment: You're welcome.